# table class not recognized/read in html/css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table which should have the class "table-class", however the class is not even recognized/read and the properties are not displayed in the table. I am using the azure appServiceEditor and when I run the code the output is just a default styled table, so the properties of the class="table-class" are not read. However, when I insert any other class istead of "table-class" the properties are displayed. I don't see where the problem is.

```css
.table-class {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  z-index: 10000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: white;
}

.table-class td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.table-class tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<table class="table-class">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you describe more what isn’t working because the snippet you have provided seems to work. What is the exact context in which it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  z-index: 10000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: white;
}

.table td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

use this code instead of table-class

Comment: still doesn't work :/